# message-driven-channel-adapter: Polling false/phantom messages from queue

Tags: spring, spring-integration, ibm-mq

We are using spring integration and daily in our logs we can see below stacktrace. Other JMS adapters are working fine, we think only below one is missing something:

Spring integration configuration:

```
    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter concurrent-consumers="1" id="jmsInLOAN" destination="queueLOAN" channel="LOANCommonDataChannel" acknowledge="transacted" />
```

Please find below MQ statistics of Put and Msgs read count, there should be exact count of Message read by adapter. I am worried about spring integration's message-driven-channel-adapter of reading extra messages from queue. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
WARN  07/Jan/2016 09:04:15,438 [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#23-1] springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - [SYSTEM_ID=HBUSLOANIQ] [MESSAGE_ID=null] Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: unsupported payload type [com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage]
        at org.springframework.integration.xml.DefaultXmlPayloadConverter.convertToDocument(DefaultXmlPayloadConverter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.integration.xml.DefaultXmlPayloadConverter.convertToNode(DefaultXmlPayloadConverter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.integration.xml.router.XPathRouter.getChannelIdentifiers(XPathRouter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.determineTargetChannels(AbstractMessageRouter.java:247)
        at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:211)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of valid and poisonous(which has a payload type [com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage]) messages we were getting onto queue. Valid messages processed well, but poisounous messages not able to digest by application and send to the BackoutQueue.

In our case, BOQ threshold is 3 that means 3 times my application will try to consume a perticular message and if the message backout 3 times then it will be moved to BOQ queue and (msgs read - msgs put)/3 on LOAIQ == the msgs put on to BOQ queue at that sampling interval. From msgs put on BOQ queue, we can see how many messages are backout from LOAIQ queue. That is why the message read count is more than that of msg received.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the unconverted JMS message (`com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage`) to the XML Payload converter...

```
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: unsupported payload type [com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage]
    at org.springframework.integration.xml.DefaultXmlPayloadConverter.convertToDocument(DefaultXmlPayloadConverter.java:76)
```

Perhaps you have set `extract-payload` to `false` ?

Although it's not in the configuration you show.

Turning on DEBUG logging will show the payload type of messages passing through the system.

Comment: This happening in live envi and hence can't be checked. Though all the received messages on queues are processing fine.
Down the line we have **xpath-router** and extract-payload is true in my case(by default)

Comment: I don't know how you arrived at those statistics but they make no sense to me. You can't read more messages from a queue that are put into it (unless there is a an exception/rollback - but since I don't know the source of that data, I can't speculate). The bottom line is you somehow have sent an unconverted message to the xpath router. You need to look over your configuration very carefully but I fear your only option is to enable DEBUG logging - it is extremely unlikely to be a bug in listener container/message-driven adapter.

Comment: The the MQ stats we got from IBM mq team, for other queues both the cols are equal values.

Comment: So the additional reads are likely due to the failures/rollbacks - the messages are re-fetched after the failure. You need to figure out why the raw JMS Message is reaching the router; it's impossible for that to happen with `extract-payload` set to true (unless, of course, the payload is a serialized (`com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage`) - who produces these messages? What is __its__ configuration?

Comment: We are not sure who is producing these false messages(com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage), but now come to know that half of the count of Msg put are going to BACKOUTQUEUE. If you see the Message read count is exactly 2.5 times more than the Msg put. So now Read count 1(by application for valid messages) + 1(by BOQ)+ .5(?) not sure about .5 read count. Any guesses.